# How can I stop one jQuery script from conflicting with another?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 scripts running on a site I am developing and one is conflicting with the other

The second one will only work if the first one is missing. I'm not a jQuery expert by any means so I don't know what the problem is.

You can see examples here;

The first page is fine, the second (sample-page) has a text resizer that only works when the slideshow script (the first page) is removed.

Comment: I'd have to look at the scripts to get a better idea on what's going on, but I have a strong feeling that you might want to look at & use `jQuery.noconflict()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your html you have some errors like closing a script tag like an image tag (the script tag is not self-closing) and on the sample page you have the following code:

```
<p>text size 
  <a href="#" 
  <a href="#" class="increaseFont">+</a> 
  <a href="#" class="decreaseFont">-</a>
</p>
```

See if correcting your html improves the functionality.

Comment: I've checked all that and still nothing. The half finished anchor tag was my fault, I was adding another link but got sidetracked and forgot about it.

Comment: You have this line of code which is generating errors on your page in the first custom code in your head `$('#left-preview').find('img').fadeOut(500).delay(1000).console.log(this);`. When I've commented this line the text resize started working. The `console` is not a function.

Comment: Sorry for this other comment but if you want to add logging in a chain you can use `.log(what you want to log)` so your line should become `$('#left-preview').find('img').fadeOut(500).delay(1000).log(this);`

Comment: Ahhhh I see. That part isn't my code, it's another developer's. Thanks for pointing out what the erorr was though. I'll raise the subject with him. Thanks a lot.